# parse lastname, firstname and truncate and caps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field stores customer name all in one column: John, Dao. Names are stored as Lastname, FirstName.

What I need to do is list last name in CAPS, *truncated at 10 characters*, followed by first initial of first name (first initial Caps Letter). For example John, Dao needs to be displayed as JOHN D.

Comment: In what language? Pure SQL? PHP? Python?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
DECLARE @FullName varchar(50) = 'Smithxxxxxxxxx, John';

SELECT UPPER(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @FullName)-1), 1, 10) ) as LastName
, UPPER( LTRIM( SUBSTRING(@FullName, CHARINDEX(',', @FullName) +1, 2))) as FirstName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--Example 1 
    DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(50) = 'Smithxxxxxxxxx, John';

    SELECT  UPPER(LEFT(@FullName,
                       CHARINDEX(',', @FullName) - 1)) AS LastName ,
            UPPER(LEFT(REPLACE(RIGHT(@FullName,
                                     LEN(@FullName)
                                     - CHARINDEX(',',
                                        @FullName) - 1),
                               ', ', ''), 1)) AS FirstName
-------------------------------------
--Example 2
    DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(50) = 'Smithxxxxxxxxx, John';

    SELECT  UPPER(LEFT(@FullName,
                       CHARINDEX(',', @FullName) - 1)) AS LastName ,
            UPPER(LEFT(REPLACE(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@FullName),
                                        CHARINDEX(',',
                                        REVERSE(@FullName)))),
                               ', ', ''), 1)) AS FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in SQLite:

```
sqlite> create table customer(lastname string, firstname string);
sqlite> insert into customer values("VerylongNameIndeed", "alex");
sqlite> SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR(lastname, 1, 10)), UPPER(SUBSTR(firstname, 1, 1)) FROM customer;
```

The result: `VERYLONGNA|A`

**EDIT:** I've just realised that the names are both stored as a single column in the question, so here's an amended version of the above:

```
sqlite> create table customer(name string);
sqlite> insert into customer values("john, dao");
sqlite> insert into customer values("VeryLongName, alex");
sqlite> SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 1, MIN(10, INSTR(name, ",")-1))), UPPER(SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name, ",")+2, 1)) FROM customer;
```

The result:

```
JOHN|D
VERYLONGNA|A
```

Comment: Thank you John - I tried your command in TSQL but I get min requires in argument. Can you please help? It is in SQL Server..

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't have access to an SQL Server database at the moment; perhaps someone who does could amend/build on this answer to more specifically answer your question. In the meanwhile, I'll re-tag your question so that it specifically asks for SQL Server answers.